# Unable to load shapefile into ArcGIS online

Tags: arcgis-online

I'm trying to upload a shapefile to ArcGIS online.
The shapefile contains the .dbf, .prj, .sbn, .sbx, .shx, and .shp files.  I zipped these together into a zip file.  When I try to upload the zip file into ArcGIS on-line I get this message - 'Unable to import this shapefile'

I have tried using both Chrome and Microsoft Edge.  Any suggestions on how to import a shapefile into ArcGIS online.

Comment: Are you using the Map Viewer Add button or some other method?  https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/shapefiles.htm

Comment: Has the same shapefile (set of files) been tested in ArcMap or QGIS successfully?  (Or any other GIS software.)